# Onclick button then swap between two dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need onclick of a button I'm wanting to SWAP the selected option between two dropdown value in a select list to correspond to the button that was clicked.

This is what I have so far,
pERHAPS my jQUERY something wrong , Kindly advise

HTML FirstDropDown:

```
<li class="zhuanzhangLiCont">
           <strong>转出：</strong>
           <select name="out" class="select_main" style="width: 225px;">   
           <option value="0">中心钱包</option>
           <option value="132">体育188</option><option value="128">真人娱乐ＥＡ</option><option value="134">真人娱乐
                </li>
```

HTML SecondDropDown:

```
<li class="zhuanzhangLiCont">
               <strong>转入：</strong>
               <select name="out" class="select_main" style="width: 225px;">   
               <option value="0>BMW</option>
                <option value="52">SPORTS188</option><option value="128">BBIN</option><option value="134">真人娱乐
                    </li>
```

HTML button :

```
<li class="exchange"><span>点击交换</span></li>
```

jQUERY :

```
function initList(gameCodeList) {
    var outList = $("select[name='out']");
    var inList = $("select[name='in']");
    outList.append("<option value='0'>中心钱包</option>");
    for (var i in gameCodeList) {
        var game = gameCodeList[i];
        var gameString = "<option value='" + game.id + "'>" + game.name + "</option>";
        outList.append(gameString);
        inList.append(gameString);
    }
    outList.change(function () {
        inList.empty();
        if (outList[0].selectedIndex === 0)
            inList.append(outList.children().slice(1).clone());
        else
            inList.append(outList.children().eq(0).clone());
    });
    $("li.exchange").click(function () {
        var outListIndex = outList[0].selectedIndex;
        if (outListIndex === 0)
            outList[0].selectedIndex = inList[0].selectedIndex + 1;
        else {
            outList[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        outList.change();
        if (outListIndex !== 0)
            inList[0].selectedIndex = outListIndex - 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: The question looks unclear. Do you want to toggle the select boxes on click of the button or do you want the selected values of both dropdowns to be same at any time onchange?

Comment: @karan3112 i want to onclick class exchange then the two dropdown value will be swap

Comment: Still not sure if this is what you are looking for [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3h8jry7/)

Comment: @karan3112 Hi karan , your working is perfect but when i try to click other value , its seem turn in blank .i have updated the jquery .. but my jquery not working , could you help me have a look?

Comment: the values of both the dropdowns should be same. For eg. if value `aa` is not preset in selectbox 2 then it will show blank.